# i want to display data which is coming from loop in a table form

Tags: php

My PHP Code is Given Below.

```
 <?php  
     for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $sid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['STOREID'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']; 
        $Product=get_product_name($pid,$sid);
        $price=get_price($pid,$sid);
        echo $Product;
 ?>
      <table border='1'>
         <tr>
           <th>Ordered Product</th
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>   
     </table>
```

I want to display the product in table under Ordered Product.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: *"I want to display"* - Well, the echos are there. So, what's the problem?

Comment: there are 3 products so table  contents is also displaying three times

Comment: Ya code is working without errors...only help me how to display product under there labels

Comment: can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which format you're willing to display. Let me show an example:

```html
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Ordered Product</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <?php 

        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
          $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
          $sid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['STOREID'];
          $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']; 
          $Product=get_product_name($pid,$sid);
          $price=get_price($pid,$sid);

      ?>

     <tr>
       <th><?php echo $product ?></th>
       <th><?php echo $price ?></th>
       <th><?php echo $q ?></th>
     </tr> 
 
     <?php } ?>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

One suggestion that I'd like to provide is to avoid writing HTML codes within echo. It's the best if you keep the PHP and HTML codes separeted.

Hope this helps!

Peace! xD

Comment: Thanks for your but this code is showing lots of syantex eroore

Comment: It's just the pattern that you should follow. Could you let me know what syntax errors you're facing, please?